# Can't assign custom UITableViewCell within custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

In my storyboard, if I have a UIViewController that inherits from a custom class, can I create a custom class for a UITableViewCell within a tableview inside that UIViewController?

I've tried to do the above, but when I try to connect outlets, I can only drag to the parent ViewController file, and not to the connected TableViewCell file. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect outlets of your cell.

1. You need to assign the class of custom table view cell in storyboard.
2. Select the table view cell while dragging to connect outlets.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking 2 questions:

1. "can I create a custom class for a UITableViewCell"?
   Yes, you can use a custom class for your UITableViewCell. Simply select the cell and in the class inspector, enter the custom class.
2. "I can only drag to the parent ViewController"
   That's also correct. For static cells, you can link them to outlets in the view controller. Note that for dynamic cells, you'll need to create them in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.